# How to make the edit command open the file in the first non NERDTree buffer window

Tags: neovim, buffers, plugin-nerdtree

so whenever I open a file be it from using FZF, NERDTree or directly using edit, IF I happen to be in the NERDTree buffer it will open the file in the buffer.

How do I make it so that whenever a file is open (no matter how) it will open in the first non NERDTree buffer/window so that NERDTree remains open no matter what?

Comment: Obligatory article: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/).

Comment: That's interesting, I think I've read that before. My main reason for wanting to know this is singular, I get annoyed when the file opens in the extremely narrow NERDTree buffer view, thus I now have to close the narrow buffer view, open the file in the main view and then IF I need to re-open NERDTree (less of a thing since I use FZF but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue bothered me for a long time.

For fzf there is a discussion about it on github. They came up with some keybindings:

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader><Leader> (expand('%') =~ 'NERD_tree' ? "\<c-w>\<c-w>" : '').":FZF\<cr>"
```

but this post is the most promising https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/453#issuecomment-366466757

> It's kind of hacky because I do "code injection" by adding the
>   g:launching_fzf variable inside the layout configuration. There may be
>   a more elegant solution but in the meantime it works and I didn't have
>   to change the FZF plugin source code.

and this is his code

```
let g:fzf_layout = { 'window': 'let g:launching_fzf = 1 | keepalt topleft 100split enew' }

autocmd FileType nerdtree let t:nerdtree_winnr = bufwinnr('%')
autocmd BufWinEnter * call PreventBuffersInNERDTree()

function! PreventBuffersInNERDTree()
  if bufname('#') =~ 'NERD_tree' && bufname('%') !~ 'NERD_tree'
    \ && exists('t:nerdtree_winnr') && bufwinnr('%') == t:nerdtree_winnr
    \ && &buftype == '' && !exists('g:launching_fzf')
    let bufnum = bufnr('%')
    close
    exe 'b ' . bufnum
  endif
  if exists('g:launching_fzf') | unlet g:launching_fzf | endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Do you know how to alter `keepalt topleft 100split enew` so it opens in the bottom? my default layout is `\'down': '~20%'`

Answer (score 0):

My setup, for someone who may want to improve NERDTree behavior.

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree let t:nerdtree_winnr = bufwinnr('%')
autocmd BufWinEnter * call PreventBuffersInNERDTree()

function! PreventBuffersInNERDTree()
  if bufname('#') =~ 'NERD_tree' && bufname('%') !~ 'NERD_tree'
    \ && exists('t:nerdtree_winnr') && bufwinnr('%') == t:nerdtree_winnr
    \ && &buftype == '' && !exists('g:launching_fzf')
    let bufnum = bufnr('%')
    close
    exe 'b ' . bufnum
    call ToggleNerdTree()
  endif
endfunction
```

"close" will close origin nerdtree pane, and ToggleNerdTree() will reopen it.

```
function NotNerdTreePane()
  return bufname('%') !~# 'NERD_tree_' && winnr("$") > 1 && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && &modifiable && exists("g:NERDTree")
endfunction

function ToggleNerdTree()
  if g:NERDTree.IsOpen() 
    :NERDTreeClose
  else 
    :NERDTreeFind
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter *  if (NotNerdTreePane() && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()) | NERDTreeFind | wincmd p | endif
autocmd SessionLoadPost * if (NotNerdTreePane() && !g:NERDTree.IsOpen()) | NERDTreeFind | wincmd p | endif 
autocmd VimLeave * NERDTreeClose
```

NotNerdTreePane() will check current pane and when you enter a buf, it will help to find current file to show in nerdtree.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! We encourage answers to accompany code with some explanation of what it's doing, to make it easier for others to follow along.